# assembly - opcodes vs. nasm instructions

Tags: assembly, nasm, opcode

So I've tried to get into assembly lately and found myself genuinely confused with how NASM works. As far as I understood it is kind of a 'compiler' for assembly that converts (mnemic) instructions to actual machine code. Now I was wondering what the difference between the instructions listed in the NASM manual (www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdocb.html) and the opcodes my machine takes is? Like, let's pretend my Intel processor has some kind of secret opcode that no one knows about and is not listed in the manual, would NASM still be able to assemble it? Or would it just return 'invalid instruction'? And say I knew the machine code format of the opcode, would I be able to insert it manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NASM supports what NASM supports.

There could indeed be "internal" instructions, or instructions introduced after your version of NASM was built, which it then wouldn't know about.

Those (or indeed *any* instruction) can be encoded manually by you using `db` sequences, or similar.

Comment: Your first paragraph is correct (NASM just has a table of mnemonics), but it does know about some instructions that Intel doesn't document in the ISA.  see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This [old version of the nasm manual](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html) includes some instructions that Intel doesn't document, but that NASM supports.  (That link is from the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

These are "secret opcodes" that people *do* know about.  I assume people have tested every possible sequence of up to 3 or 4 bytes at least, to find undocumented opcodes like this.  You don't need NASM to know how to encode them, of course, since you can use `db` to assemble whatever bytes you want into the object file.

This isn't an answer to what you actually asked, but might be more along the lines of what you wanted to know.  Like @500... says, NASM is just a program that looks up byte sequences from a table of known mnemonics.  It doesn't even have to run on an x86 CPU, and there isn't an interface to query the CPU for the names of instructions.

You might want to edit your question into one that has a more interesting answer.

---

For example:

`SALC                          ; D6                   [8086,UNDOC]`

> SALC is an early undocumented instruction similar in concept to SETcc (section A.150). Its function is to set AL to zero if the carry flag is clear, or to 0xFF if it is set.

It actually works in 32bit mode on my Core2 CPU.  (NASM and YASM both reject it when assembling 64bit code).

In case it wasn't obvious **DO NOT USE THIS IN PORTABLE CODE**.  It's subject to breakage on some future CPU that uses D6 as the first byte of the encoding for some other instruction.  The `D6` entry in the opcode map in Appendix A of Intel's insn ref manual is empty.

> All blanks in opcode maps are reserved and must not be used. Do not depend on the operation of
>   undefined or blank opcodes.

---

The [current version of the NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdocb.html) doesn't list descriptions, but does still list all mnemonics, including the ones tagged `UNDOC`.  Presumably that appendix was getting too bloated with SSE instructions.